# Return list of values of one column grouped by another column in Django viewset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have a model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    email = models.EmailField()
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'entries'
```

What I want to achieve is the viewset to return list of `content` and `upload_date` values per single email (since many entries can have the same email value), like that:

```
[
    {
        "email": "address1@test.test",
        "entries": [
            {
                "upload_date": "2020-09-03",
                "content": "test content 1"
            },
            {
                "upload_date": "2020-09-02",
                "content": "test content 2"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "email": "address2@test.test",
        "entries": [
            {
                "upload_date": "2020-09-03",
                "content": "test content 11"
            },
            {
                "upload_date": "2020-09-02",
                "content": "test content 12"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

I tried messing around with `.values()` and `.annotate()`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer with [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) **itertools** function :

```py
def entry_converter(entry):
    return {'upload_date': entry.upload_date, 'content': entry.content}


def grouping_key(entry):
    return entry.email


from itertools import groupby
entries = Entry.objects.order_by('email')
grouped_entries = [dict(email=key, entries=list(map(entry_converter, group))) for key, group in groupby(entries, key=grouping_key)]
```

### Update 1

Integration with DRF ViewSet

```py
def entry_converter(entry):
    return {'upload_date': entry.id, 'content': entry.id}


def grouping_key(entry):
    return entry.email


def group_entries(entries):
    return [
        dict(email=key, entries=list(map(entry_converter, group))) for key, group in groupby(entries, key=grouping_key)
    ]


class EntrySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = '__all__'


class EntryViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Entry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntrySerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset().order_by('email')

        data = group_entries(queryset)

        page = self.paginate_queryset(data)
        if page is not None:
            return self.get_paginated_response(page)

        return Response(data)
```

Keep in mind that I haven't used `.filter_queryset()` method of ModelViewSet as it may modify the queryset by adding wrong ordering or wrong filtering. Because `groupby` function needs sorted data as an input. Also, I have not overridden `ModelSerializer` class for generalizing `.list()` method of `ModelViewSet` as it may create extra complexity.

Comment: Thanks already. Could you please elaborate, how this approach would look like when embedded in Django's viewset notation? Thanks in advance!